# Is a public instance behind a Load Balancer that much less secure than a private instance behind a NAT Gateway? Due to what risks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I want to understand the *relative security gained* when comparing a private instance protected behind a NAT Gateway and a public instance that only accepts connections from its Load Balancer.

*How* (due to what specific risks) is the latter less secure than the former?

To be upfront, my motivation is to understand how to **minimize cost** for **acceptable security** in my AWS network infrastructure. NAT Gateways add cost, and I want to be convinced the costs are necessary before springing for them.

I'm starting from AWS's reference **three-tier architecture** for a VPC where:

- a *public subnet* hosts a *Load Balancer* (for incoming connections) and a *NAT Gateway* (for outgoing), which both must have *Public IPs*
- a *private subnet* for *application instances*, which only have *Private IPs* and communicate out via the earlier NAT gateway
- a *protected subnet* for data (out of scope for this question)

I get how eliminating its public IP protects an instance from unsolicited external connections.

But: Can't I do the same by configuring the security group for an instance with a public IP (which is necessary to use the internet gateway directly) to only accept incoming connections from its load balancer?

I want to understand: Is there a *sufficiently secure* alternative network architecture which **does away with NAT Gateways** (or NAT instances — basically, NAT Tax)? Is there a sufficiently secure **two-tier architecture**?

For example, how much *less* secure (due to what specific risks) would this two-tier architecture be?

- a *public subnet* hosts a Load Balancer *and* application instances, and instance security groups only accept connections from the Load Balancer
- a *private subnet* hosts data, and only connects with application instances

Thanks for your time. I'm new to AWS (and StackOverflow) and am looking forward to learn more.

Comment: If you design it right, the more layers you create, the better security you gain, you can use a firewall subnet if you want. Other answers are enough for your question, just want to say ALB can use to expose targets in both public and private subnets. For 3-tier architecture, you can read this blog: https://stratus10.com/blog/aws-best-practices-3-tier-infrastructure

Comment: @FranxiHidro What do you mean by "ALB can use to expose targets"? Expose in what way? Is it a non-obvious security risk?

Comment: what is the purpose of internet-facing ALB? What is target group?

Comment: I understand. By "expose targets" you mean i can use ALB to target instances in both public and private subnets. Right. I feared you meant an alternate meaning for "expose", as in, compromising the security of. I worried you were saying ALBs somehow introduced a security risk and could be used to compromise target instances. But you aren't, thankfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two reasons for wanting to use a Private Subnet:

1. More layers of security = Better security
2. It's the traditional way of doing it in non-Cloud networks and security practitioners like doing things a traditional way

The fact is, **using Security Groups is a perfectly acceptable way** of blocking access to an Amazon EC2 instance. It's a form of security that isn't available in traditional networks since they normally apply security at the subnet-level while Security Groups can be applied at the resource-level.

You could configured the Inbound rules in the Security Group of your EC2 instances to only accept incoming connections from the Load Balancer security group. This will stop any other connections -- both within the VPC and from the Internet, even if the instances have a Public IP address.

In many corporations, **improved security is more important than cost**, so they are happy to pay extra to have more 'layers' of security. This way, if one layer is incorrectly configured and somebody gains access to something they should not be allowed to access, there is additional security that can (hopefully) prevent them from further access. It's always a trade-off between cost and 'risk appetite'.

Oh, there is something a 3rd reason for using a Private Subnet, which is to route all Outgoing traffic through a NAT Gateway to **make all traffic appear to be coming from a single IP address**, which is useful when whitelisting IP addresses with external services.

Answer (score 3):

Setting instances in a public subnet with security group (SG) allowing incoming connections from a SG of a ALB or CLB is often good enough.

Placing instances in a private subnet and using NAT is still better, as its much easier to accidentally change SG of instances in a public subnet and allow direct internet access, then to move instances from private to public subnets.

Also NAT gives you one static public IP for all your instances in a private subnet. This often is impotent if you work with external API which requires single IP to whitelist.

Comment: Illustrating the risk — that accidentally misconfiguring your only layer of security means immediate insecurity — really helps, thanks.